# bootstrap datetimepicker Max date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't make bootstrap prevent user from entering date max than today is date this is my function

```
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',maxDate:new Date()

  });
```

thats all rest just input and import of bibliothec

```
<div id="datetimepicker3" class="input-append date">
  <input type="text" name="datewo" value="<?php echo $row['date'];?>"    readonly></input>
  <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript " src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: thats all rest just input and import of bibliothec

<div id="datetimepicker3" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text" name="datewo" value="<?php echo $row['date'];?>"    readonly></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>

<script
     src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation (assuming this is the plugin: https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to set a maximum date you would use the endDate property:

```
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    endDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: maxDate would be correct when using this plugin: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: this didnt work with this format  'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'

Comment: @liane uses different format strings (momentJS) http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: the problem that I need this format to save it in database like datetime